# Wordpress Backend Fine, All Themes Return a Blank Page?

Tags: front-end, fatal-error

I have this issue, where I can't access the frontend without a blank page anymore. It drives me crazy.

The backend seems to be up just fine, but the frontend is white. When trying to chose another theme (twentyten) this one also returns white, already in the preview.

What can I possibly do?

Edit 1:

This is what I get

`Notice: Constant TEMPLATEPATH already defined in /site.com/html/wp-includes/default-constants.php on line 278`

`Notice: Constant STYLESHEETPATH already defined in /site.com/html/wp-includes/default-constants.php on line 284`

`Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /site.com/html/wp-includes/default-constants.php:278) in /site.com/html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 897`

Comment: What Plugins do you have active?

Comment: At the moment I disabled all plugins!

Comment: What Theme are you using? What version of WordPress are you using? Have you customized wp-config.php to define STYLESHEETPATH and/or TEMPLATEPATH?

Comment: Thank you! I actually had STYLESHEETPATH and TEMPLATEPATH defined for additional speed in wp-config.php and have left it uncommented in this version of the backup. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you have ftp access to your site, go to the root. There is a line in wp-config.cfg:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

Switch it to:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

Upon returning to one of the blank pages, you'll notice an error message which can shed some light on what is going wrong. From there you may either correct the issue, or bring that error back here and we can offer more help.

Comment: Thanks Drew! However I can't quite make sense of what these errors actually are saying. I'm going to need to post since there is not enough space here.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments above: check for custom `define()` calls for `STYLESHEETPATH` and `TEMPLATEPATH` in `wp-config.php`.